# How to include meatamask in dapp?

Tags: blockchain, metamask

i am new to the blockchain, ethereum. I am trying to include metamask in my nodejs application. How to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MetaMask is a browser extension, so it can't be used from Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is not browser client facing...then you cannot connect to Metamask.

If your code is browser client facing...then you just have to look for the exposed `window.web3` variable. Most people do this by checking the `typeof web3` to see if it exists.

Here is an example from [this article](https://medium.com/@merunasgrincalaitis/the-ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-and-deploy-a-fully-descentralized-dapp-in-ethereum-18f0cf6d7e0e):

```
if (typeof web3 != 'undefined') {
  console.log("Using web3 detected from external source like Metamask")
  this.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
} else {
  this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
}
```

Most basic tutorials should show you how.